# Regex match and split string in C#

Tags: c#, regex, split, pattern-matching, match

I have some ASCII documents in the following format:

```
[section heading]
paragraphs......

[section heading]
paragraphs......
...
```

> Note: heading text are always enclosed in some specific pattern (e.g. `[` `]` in the above example)

I want to split the file into separate sections (each with a *heading* and the *content*).

What would be the most efficient way to parse the above document?

Using `Regex.Match()` I can extract the headings, but not the subsequent text content.

Using `Regex.Split()` I can grab the content, but not the related headings.

Is it possible combine these two `Regex` methods to parse the document? Are there better ways to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(\[[^\]]*\])\n([\s\S]*?)(?=\n\[|$)
```

You can try this.Grab the group 1 and group 2.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/gU4aG0/1

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string search = "\[([\w ]+)\]([^\[]*)";
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(yourtext, search))
    {
        string heading = match.Groups[1];
        string text = match.Groups[2];
    }
```

The regular expression capture both the heading *and* the paragraph. Thanks to capturing groups (between parentheses), you can extract both of them by iterating over the matches.